# Submit action is not working inside Kendo UI TabStrip for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

**Submit action is not working inside Kendo UI TabStrip for MVC.**

Can someone share a link where i can see a sample program of Kendo UI Tabstrip with event handling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even try looking for this?

[KendoUI TabStrip events example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/tabstrip/events.html)

I added a fiddle that has a button in the first and third tab.  They're basic and just trigger an alert.

```
<button id="alertHello">Hello!</button>

$('#alertHello').on('click', function(){
    alert('Hello!');
});
```

[Fiddle with button in 1st and 3rd tab](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/N6jfu/)

Is what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, I have seen this link.  Actually I having few controls (including a submit button) in a Kendo UI TabStrip. I have trigger an action with  Submit. When i am try to submit the action is not even called, but it work's fine if the controls are outside. (Not in TabStrip).

Comment: If that answer helps you out.  Will you mark it correct please?

Comment: Thank you so much. Will the same method work for a Submit Button?

Comment: You'll have to have a <form> element to go along with the submit button to get the data.  Or, you can use the example I showed and just post the data through ajax.